# Text is replacing while scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to increment decrement label value of a particular row. I am using following method, it is working but when I scroll the table view then values are replacing with other's row.

Like I am showing two row on a screen according to design so while scrolling, first row's label value is replacing with forth row label and so on.

```
@IBAction func plusBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var cell:TableViewCell = self.tebleView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell as! TableViewCell

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

    cell = (self.tebleView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell)!

    if cell.tag == sender.tag {
        print(sender.tag)
        print(cell.countLbl.tag)
        cell.countLbl.text = "\(Int(cell.countLbl.text!)! + 1)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Cells get reused when they move off screen, so you need to make sure that's not what's going on.

Comment: you need to set a increment decrements change in main array values of particular data. and on change it reload the particular cell and when you chagne the value for it that come from main array so that wont change after scroll.

Comment: You need a else after the cell.tag == sender.tag { } else {cell.countLbl.text = ""}

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:TableViewCell = self.tebleView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell as! TableViewCell
            cell.plusBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.countLbl.tag = indexPath.row;
            return cell
        }

Comment: its a action method there is just a temp setting you have to do change that value in main array @SachinVas

Comment: Hmmm, But is their any way so that we can give different identifier to each cell besides "Cell" .

Comment: like index path.row as an identifier, tried it but i got crash...Otherwise i will take an array.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you are reusing the cells - `dequeueReusableCell` each time you need to display a new cell, so what's happening here is the first row disappears and when it is redisplayed, you are using the cell that was used for row 4.

The solution to this is to keep a track of your counter in an array outside of the tableView (table, not teble :-) )  Something like this...

```
var tableDataCounters : [Int] = []

// set up your data ...

cell.countLbl.text = "\(tableDataCounters[indexPath.row] + 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: )` method of `UITableView`, you are initially creating cells and later on reusing those created cells. You are facing this problem due to this. Since you have only one row whose text you need to change, it's better to keep the text for that row stored externally. For the `plusBtnAction`, it's better to do the following:

```
var cellLabelTextArray: [String] = [] // populate this with data for each cell

@IBAction func plusBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

     var cell:TableViewCell = self.tebleView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell as! TableViewCell

     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

     var cellLabelText = cellLabelTextArray[indexPath.row]
     cellLabelText = "\(Int(cellLabelText) + 1)"

     cellLabelTextArray[indexPath.row] = cellLabelText

     if let visiblePaths: [IndexPath] = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        if visiblePaths.contains(indexPath) {
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, we are checking if the indexPath is visible. If it is, then reload that particular indexPath. Otherwise, we don't need to.

Comment: @ KrishnaCA
I have a plus minus button on each row so i want only that particular label value should change whose plus minus being clicked.
It is happening value is changed accordingly.But when i scroll the value first row's label value replace with forth row as i am showing only 2 row on screen.I know this is because reusability of cell..
I want to give unique identifier to each but don't know how to give in swift.

Comment: @TBI, I updated the answer. It's better to keep an array and update it accordingly. You don't need a unique identifier in this case.